# java.lang.NumberFormatException at double.parseDouble

Tags: java, double

I used BlueJ

The program compiles properly but when i try to execute it, it says

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty string (in sun.misc.FLoating Decimal)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
at Employee.accept(Employee.java:12)
at Employee.main(Employee.java:26)
```

```
import java.io.*;
class Employee {
  String name;
  double gross;
  double basic;
  char grade;
  int age;
  public void accept() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter name,age,grade and basic");
    name = br.readLine();
    age = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    grade = (char) br.read();
    basic = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
    double da = 0.25 * basic;
    double hra = 0.15 * basic;
    double pf = 0.0833 * basic;
    double gross = basic + da + hra;
    double net = gross - pf;
  }
  public void display() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Age : " + age + "Grade : " + grade + "Basic : " + basic + "Gross pay : " + gross);
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    Employee obj = new Employee();
    obj.accept();
    obj.display();
  }
}
```

Comment: problem may be you string not in correct format like it may contain spaces or some other chars. Try to trim the string before converting into double.

Comment: You can see you error. It clearly mention that your string was empty.

Comment: You should be checking every `readLine()` result for null before you do anything else with it.

Answer (score 0):

As i have mention above comments that in your code, string which is you are going to parse it's not parsable due to string not in correct format or string is empty. As i can see in you code sample and your exception above you have posted it clearly mention that your string is empty, So here you have to check whether your string is empty or null before conversion then only perform type conversion. I am giving you code sample please check it may help you:

```
import java.io.*;
class Employee {
  String name;
  double gross;
  double basic;
  char grade;
  int age;
  public void accept() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter name,age,grade and basic");
    name = br.readLine();
    String ageStr = br.readLine();
    if(ageStr != null || ageStr != 0)
     age = Integer.parseInt();
    else
    // do your else logic
    grade = (char) br.read();
    String basicStr = br.readLine();
    if(basicStr != null || basicStr != "")
        basic = Double.parseDouble(basicStr);
    else
        // do your else logic
    double da = 0.25 * basic;
    double hra = 0.15 * basic;
    double pf = 0.0833 * basic;
    double gross = basic + da + hra;
    double net = gross - pf;
  }
  public void display() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Age : " + age + "Grade : " + grade + "Basic : " + basic + "Gross pay : " + gross);
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    Employee obj = new Employee();
    obj.accept();
    obj.display();
  }
}
```

I hope you will find your solution with that.